# Core data unable to find source store during migrtion

Tags: objective-c, core-data

All of my models are within a single schema, they are all versioned individually. I'm using a mapping model that changes an attribute type from an NSString to a Double. By doing the following `$source.identifier.doubleValue`

[image]

Yet, I still receive the following error: `reason = "Can't find model for source store";`. [Here](https://gist.github.com/IoDmitri/81180281234305cee2fc) is a link to a Gist with the full error.

Here is the code for creating the persistentStore (storeURL for example only):

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        __block BOOL exceptionOccured = NO;
            NSError *dbError = nil;

            NSDictionary *sqlPragmaOptions = @{
                                               @"synchronous" : @"0",
                                               @"journal_mode" : @"TRUNCATE",
                                               };
            //@"fullfsync" : @"0"};
            NSDictionary *options = @{
                                      NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                      NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                      NSSQLitePragmasOption : sqlPragmaOptions
                                      };
        NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self fijiDBName]]];
            if(![_persistantStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                               configuration:nil
                                                         URL:[self storeURL]
                                                     options:options
                                                                  error:&dbError]){
                NSLog(@"ERROR initializing shared Coordinator: %@, %@", [dbError localizedDescription], [dbError localizedDescription]);
#ifdef DEBUG
                abort();
#endif
            }
```

Here is how my ManagedObjectModel is created:

```
-(NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel{
    if (_mom != nil){
        return _mom;
    }

    _mom = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    NSAssert(_mom, @"%@, %@ NO Model to generate", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    return _mom;
}
```

Comment: your recent model is 20 so shouldn't it has green tick with it ?

Comment: @Misha Not always, its up to the developer to specify which one is the current. The mapping model has a source and destination model which is again developer specified.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of it maybe it was working earlier and broke(as much I can understand to error) when you add a new model.